# MySQL procedure to update table based on value from other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am writing a procedure that given an order number update the quantities in a warehouse.
I currently retrieve a product number `id_p` and a quantity `qt_p`.
I have a `materials` table.

```
id | qt
-------
 1 | 12
 2 |  4
```

and a `materials_x_product` table which tells for each product which materials and quantity are required to make a piece

```
id | qt_per_product | id_material | id_product
----------------------------------------------
 1 |       5        |     1       |    1
 2 |       2        |     2       |    1
```

my procedure should update the material table by reducing the quantities of the material used to make product `id_p` by `qt_per_product * qt_p` and fails and roll back if quantity of any of the materials goes below 0.
For example given the above tables and `id_p = 1` , `qt_p = 2` the expected result for the material table is

```
id | qt      id | qt 
-------      ------- 
 1 | 12  =>   1 |  2 
 2 |  4       2 |  0
```

I have tried following several answers on the topic, but the problem seems to be the fact that I have to update the rows of material table basing on the joined material and material_x_product table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the update as:

```
update materials m join
       materials_x_product mp
       on mp.id_material = m.id
    set qt = m.qt - (mp.qt_per_product * qt_p)
    where mp.product_id = ?;
```

I would recommend adding a trigger or `check` constraint to prevent values from going negative.

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly! The missing point in my case was the use of **join** in the **update** clause.